# Why do I have to enter two integer at first to proceed to the iteration? hasInt(), nextLine(), nextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I attempted to run this, I have to enter 2 integers and enters for the loop to move to the next iteration but it does not happen from the second loop?
What is the reason and what is the logic to fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinAndMaxInputChallenge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int number;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter number ");
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            boolean hasInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            if (hasInt) {
                if (number > max)
                    max = number;
                else if (number < min)
                    min = number;
            } else break;
        }
        System.out.println("Max = " + max + " Min = " + min);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

[Code & Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VPKo.png)

Comment: In my code, I used scanner.nextLine(); to consumed the NL already but it does not work well.

Comment: What do you think `nextInt` does? What do you think `hasNextInt` does?

Comment: nextInt will read and consume my Integer when I input. hasNextInt will check the input whether an Integer or not. And nextLine is to consume the \n to move the scanner to the next line.

Comment: _hasNextInt will check the input whether an Integer or not_ Which input? Note that you said that `nextInt` will **consume** one input.

Comment: From what I understand, nextInt() will consume my first Integer. So hasNextInt has no input to check because it uses nextInt inside, it will wait for my input. After I enter the second integer, I will check that integer. and nextLine() will consume that line. 
But why when it passed the first iteration, the same thing does not appear? I just proceed as normal?

Comment: `hasNextInt` does not use `nextInt` "inside" itself

Comment: sorry for the confusion. `hasNextInt` will check the next Int but not advance the scanner as `nextInt`. However, why this just happens at the first iteration but not from the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code logic is just a little off.  Check first if the kb has an int in it's buffer.  If it does, read it in, consume eol, set min or max and then break out of the while loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinAndMaxInputChallenge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int number;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter number ");
            
            boolean hasInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
            
            if (hasInt) {
                number = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();
                if (number > max)
                    max = number;
                else if (number < min)
                    min = number;
                break;
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("Max = " + max + " Min = " + min);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is clearer now. `hasNextInt` will check the buffer. You have any idea why at the first iteration it was waiting for another eol but from the second iteration, it works just fine?

Comment: because the way your code is written you first grab the int so hasNextINt() is now waiting for input.  Please accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. What does "kb" in your answer stand for?

Comment: kb --> key board